# complex hierarchal SQL query help needed please!

Tags: mysql, sql

Calling all mySQL gurus!

I am in need of a complex query for mySQL but I can't get my head around it. There are 2 tables in question:

**locations**
(columns: location_id, parent, location)
Data is split in a hierarchal fashion into Country, Region, County and Town thus:
1, 0, England (*country*)
2, 1, South West (*region*)
3, 1, South East (*region*)
4, 2, Dorset (*county*)
5, 4, Bournemouth (*town*)
6, 4, Poole (*town*)
7, 4, Wimborne (*town*)
etc up to 400+ rows of location data

**profiles**
(columns: profile_id, title, location_id)
Each row has one location ID which is ALWAYS a town (ie the last child of). Eg:
1, 'This profile has location set as Bournemouth', 5
2, 'This profile has location set as Poole', 6
etc

What I need to achieve is to return all IDs from the Locations table where itself or it's children have entries associated with it. So in the example above I would need the following location IDs returned: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6

Reasons:
1 - YES, England is parent of South West, Dorset and Bournemouth which has an entry
2 - YES, South West is parent of Dorset and Bournemouth which has an entry
3 - NO, South East has no entries under it or any of it's children
4 - YES, Dorset is parent of Bournemouth which has an entry
5 - YES, Bournemouth has an entry
6 - YES, Poole has an entry
7 - NO, Wimborne has no entries

So, is this actually possible? I attempted to do it in PHP with nested SQL queries but the script timed out so there must be a way to do this just in a SQL query?

Thanking you in advance! :)

===========

**UPDATE**

After reading through and playing with all these solutions I realised that I was going about the problem completely the wrong way. Instead of going through all the locations and returning those that have entries it makes more sense and is far more efficient to get all the entries and return the corresponding locations and then go up the hierarchy to get each location parent until the root is hit.

Thank you very much for your help, it at least made me realise that what I was attempting was unnecessary.

Comment: Can you post your table definitions and some sample data? It should be doable with join.

Comment: why are bournemouth and poole (5,6) included as they have no children - is it because they have a profile ?

Comment: Is the level of nesting of location data always the same for a town, i.e. Town->County->Region->Country, or can it vary?

Comment: @f00: bournemouth & poole are included as they are the ultimate children in the heirarchy, ie Towns. Every entry must have a town.

Comment: @JohnC: Good point. I was hoping the structure would all be the same but with the final locations data I have some Towns only have 3 levels (ie, Country, Region, Town or Country, County, Town)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have dealt with this is doing only one SQL load, and then putting references inside of the parent objects.

```
    $locations = array();

        $obj_query = "SELECT * from locations";
        $result_resource = mysql_query($obj_query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_resource) {
            $locations[$row['location_id'] = (object) $row;
        }

        foreach ($locations as $location) {
            if (isset($location->parent) {
                $locations[$location->parent]->children[] = $location;
            }
        }
```

Your object would then need a method such as this to find out whether a location is a descendant:

```
function IsAnscestorOF ($location) {
    if (empty($children)) { return false; }
    if (in_array($location, keys($this->children) {
        return true;
    } else {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
             if ($child->isAnscestor) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer as this was the solution that made me realise I was going about the problem all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

THe fact that your script timed out would indicate an infinite loop somewhere.

Considering you're making a reference to the locations table based on the child area, plus another reference to the parent area, you probalby have to use a combination of PHP & Mysql to scroll through all this - a simple JOIN statement would not work in this case, I don't think.

Also you need to alter the table so that if it's a top-level page, it has a parent_id of NULL, not 0. After you've done that..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE parent =''";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($country = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$subsql = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE parent='".$country['id']."'";
$subresult = mysql_query($subsql);
while($subregion = mysql_fetch_array($subresult)) {

$profilesql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE location_id='".$subregion['id']."'";
$profileresult = mysql_query($profilesql); 

echo mysql_num_rows($profileresult).' rows under '.$subregion['location'].'.<br />';
}

}
```

The base code is there... does anybody have a clever idea of making it work with various sub-levels? But honestly, if this were my project, I would have made separate tables for Country, and then Regions, and then City/Town. 3 tables would make the data navigation much easier.

Comment: yes, 3 tables would have been much easier but the data supplied ruled out that option. I will try this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If your php code was good you might have a nested loop in the [location -> parent] fd.  I would start there first, and just use PHP. I don't think SQL has a recursive function.

If you NEED a nested parent loop, you should write an mutation of merge|union algorithm to solve this this.

To find the nested loop in PHP

```
$ids = array();
function nestedLoopFinder($parent)
{
    global $ids;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE parent=$parent");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        if(in_array($row->location_id, $ids)) {
            die("duplicate found: $row->location_id");
        }
        $ids[] = $row->location_id;

        //recurse
        nestedLoopFinder($row->location_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some DBMS have a recursive query. Check out Oracle's "CONNECT BY PRIOR"

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason I thought that you cannot embed a function within itself... but if you can, that's the perfect way to recurse through a single-table categorization scheme that is unlimited in its depth level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your requirements but the following stored procedure example might be a good starting point for you:

**Example calls (note the included column)**

```
mysql> call location_hier(1);
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+----------+
| location_id | location            | parent_location_id | parent_location     | depth | included |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+----------+
|           1 | England (country)   |               NULL | NULL                |     0 |        1 |
|           2 | South West (region) |                  1 | England (country)   |     1 |        1 |
|           3 | South East (region) |                  1 | England (country)   |     1 |        0 |
|           4 | Dorset (county)     |                  2 | South West (region) |     2 |        1 |
|           5 | Bournemouth (town)  |                  4 | Dorset (county)     |     3 |        1 |
|           6 | Poole (town)        |                  4 | Dorset (county)     |     3 |        1 |
|           7 | Wimborne (town)     |                  4 | Dorset (county)     |     3 |        0 |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You'd call the stored procedure from php as follows:

```
$startLocationID = 1;
$result = $conn->query(sprintf("call location_hier(%d)", $startLocationID));
```

**Full script:**

http://pastie.org/1785995

```
drop table if exists profiles;
create table profiles
(
profile_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
location_id smallint unsigned null,
key (location_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into profiles (location_id) values (5),(6);

drop table if exists locations;
create table locations
(
location_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
location varchar(255) not null,
parent_location_id smallint unsigned null,
key (parent_location_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into locations (location, parent_location_id) values
('England (country)',null), 
    ('South West (region)',1),
    ('South East (region)',1),
        ('Dorset (county)',2),
            ('Bournemouth (town)',4),
            ('Poole (town)',4),
            ('Wimborne (town)',4);


drop procedure if exists location_hier;
delimiter #

create procedure location_hier
(
in p_location_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table hier(
 parent_location_id smallint unsigned, 
 location_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned default 0,
 included tinyint unsigned default 0,
 primary key (location_id),
 key (parent_location_id)
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select parent_location_id, location_id, v_depth, 0 from locations where location_id = p_location_id;
create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from locations c
        inner join tmp on c.parent_location_id = tmp.location_id and tmp.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier select c.parent_location_id, c.location_id, v_depth + 1, 0 from locations c
            inner join tmp on c.parent_location_id = tmp.location_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

    update hier inner join tmp on hier.location_id = tmp.parent_location_id
    set hier.included = 1;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

update hier inner join tmp on hier.location_id = tmp.parent_location_id
set hier.included = 1;

-- include any locations that have profiles ???

update hier inner join profiles on hier.location_id = profiles.location_id
set hier.included = 1;

-- output the results

select 
 c.location_id,
 c.location as location,
 p.location_id as parent_location_id,
 p.location as parent_location,
 hier.depth,
 hier.included
from 
 hier
inner join locations c on hier.location_id = c.location_id
left outer join locations p on hier.parent_location_id = p.location_id
-- where included = 1 -- filter in your php or here up to you !
order by
 hier.depth;

-- clean up

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #

delimiter ;

call location_hier(1);
```

Hope this helps :)